# Align input to the auto-height increase textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my code, the other inputs are aligned at the center of the textarea as i type long text. What I want is to align the input boxes at the top of the textarea while the textarea is expanding downward.

What i want example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne10A.png)

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
//var limit = 80; //height limit

textarea.oninput = function() {
  textarea.style.height = "";
  textarea.style.height = Math.min(textarea.scrollHeight) + "px";
};
```

```css
textarea {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input></td>
  <td><textarea id="textarea"></textarea></td>
  <td><input></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just align the `td`'s to the top as shown below.

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
//var limit = 80; //height limit

textarea.oninput = function() {
  textarea.style.height = "";
  textarea.style.height = Math.min(textarea.scrollHeight) + "px";
};
```

```css
textarea {
    width: 100%;
}

table td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input></td>
  <td><textarea id="textarea"></textarea></td>
  <td><input></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! One more thing, how can i apply the auto height to all of my added rows?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. but all the `td`'s in your page will get the alignment.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setheigth(e)
{
  e.style.height = "";
  e.style.height = Math.min(e.scrollHeight) + "px";
}
```

```css
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
}
td
{
   vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input></td>
  <td><textarea oninput="setheigth(this)"></textarea></td>
  <td><input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input></td>
  <td><textarea oninput="setheigth(this)"></textarea></td>
  <td><input></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! How can i apply the auto height textarea if i have added rows?

Comment: Do you mean to have several row and an textarea in each line?

Comment: Yes, because i have a add and remove rows buttons

Comment: You're a goddamn hero! Thanks man! Works fine.